# Best place to use Servant Sacrifice/Brainjack?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-x

What is the best location to get the most use out of the Servant Sacrifice/Brainjack combo before having a Flying Skell?

Comment: You might want to check [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/247563/how-can-i-quickly-level-up-my-party-members), as your question is mostly related to leveling up, I don't see why it's necessary to SS/BJ.

Comment: @Seiyria, the **reason** does not constitute the question. OP may want to use the requested answer in leveling, but **they are not asking how to level**. OP is asking a completely different question, which is not even touched on as far as I can see, in the proposed duplicate.

Comment: @Timelord64 Using the skills isn't relevant to leveling up the skill though. They just need to level up and get essentially Skill Points (I forget the actual name.) The answer to the question is "Go here to level up quickly" because that is the answer to how do I level up these skills. I guess it depends on the meta but the answer to the other questions IS the answer to this one.

Comment: @Reafexus, I have not personally read the other answer, but for a very good reason. You can not use the answers as a reason in any case for closure. OP might be in the wrong boat with how they are doing it, but this should still be answered with "best place to use SS/BJ", with an explanation on why this is not an ideal way to level.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of my question. Yes, these skills can be used to kill difficult monsters, but fundamentally this question is about how to utilize these skills together. It might need an edit to make it less ambiguous, but I think it is okay as-is.

Comment: I was obviously guilty of the same thinking. So I edited the question to remove the focus from leveling and more towards efficient use of the combo without having access to a Skell.

Answer (score 1):

The Everlasting Millesaurs around lakes in Primordia.

You have to engage in combat with the lower leveled monsters around the Millesaur and get a purple soul voice. The Millesaur will usually resist Brainjack, but it will always hit with the soul voice. After that's successful, use Servant Sacrifice and get up to 9999 EXP. It may take a few tries if Servant Sacrifice keeps missing, so you might want to up your accuracy if possible